# React-Leaflet: How to listen to LayersControl.Overlay checkbox click events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm dynamically rendering some overlay controls and wanting to bind a click event listener to the checkbox of each control. However there does not currently seem to be a way to provide a React ref to `LayersControl` or an `onClick` handler to `LayersControl.Overlay`. Is there a better approach to achieving this functionality?

**Example**:

```
<LayersControl>
  {overlays.map(el => (
    <LayersControl.Overlay
      checked={el.checked}
      key={el.id}
      name={el.label}
    >
      <GeoJsonLayer {...el} />
    </LayersControl.Overlay>
  ))}
</LayersControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ref to get the `map` instance and following listen to a `baselayerchange` event. Then using the name of your layer or the url you can implement the behavior you want.

```
const mapRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
    map.on("baselayerchange", e => {
      //do whatever
      console.log(e.name);
      switch (e.name) {
        case "OpenStreetMap.Mapnik":
          flyToParis(map);
          break;
        case "OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite":
          console.log("do something else");
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const flyToParis = map => {
    console.log(map);
    map.panTo([48.864716, 2.349014]);
  };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-how-to-listen-to-layerscontroloverlay-checkbox-click-events-jk9ck)

Comment: Interesting... while this does work for `BaseLayer` controls, it does not fire an event for `Overlay` controls.

Comment: Okay got it -- the `overlayadd|overlayremove` event fires when you toggle the checkbox.
Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Is there any way to get an event like "overlaywilladd" or "overlayclicked" or smth like it? I'd like to listen to the overlay checkbox click event and decide if the event should continue or should be blocked. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Check [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-event) for the available map layer events